# Google Cloud Vision API returning bad result?

Tags: javascript

So I'm using the Google Cloud Vision API to get back data on an image. As I was testing, I came across a large image that apparently exceeded the max byte size length. So I decided it would be good to programmatically detect if you try to do that, and stop the process before sending to Google.

When I looked at the response from google it says: `"Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes."`

Okay, so I decided to figure out how to get the byte size of a base64 image and check to see if it exceeds `10485760` before sending to google. However, I tried 2 different solutions, both resulting in a byte size of `7907945` which is not greater than the max size on Google's end.

I would post the base64, but it is pretty large and any time I try to copy and paste, it freezes my browser, so I will refrain for now. I do apologize, I like to provide all information but I can't even put it in a gist to post here. Although I will keep trying.

Instead here is my conversion code (I also tried another solution I found on SO that gave me the same result):

```
var b64str = atob(dataUri.replace('data:image/png;base64,',""));
var byteLength = b64str.length;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7907945 bytes, or roughly 7.5 MB still seem to exceed the API's max file size.

Looking at [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files), it seems like they have a 4 MB limit:

> Image files sent to the Google Cloud Vision API should not exceed 4 MB.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't even look because they give you (presumably) the max size in the error message.. I will cap it at 4 and see if that fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: Fairly sure it shows you the current size, not the max size.

Comment: Or maybe it is, but it doesn't seem to be accurate. I got `7907945` which is way off from `10485760`. I might be missing something, I could be wrong, just seems way too off.

Comment: Anyways I decided to just cap it at 4, since thats what the docs say. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the 4 comments in a row, but I have an image that exceeds 4mb that was working before. I'm still going to check this answer, perhaps Google has some wiggle room on the 4 mb (the image I'm referring to was just a bit over 4mb after converting). Just very confusing all around (not your fault, Google's fault). Thanks again